# Which is your favourite javascript modal plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, modal-dialog

I'm trying to choose a JavaScript modal plugin to use it on a web site.

I used to use nyroModal (without making any research on this topic) but they have updated it recently and all of the API has changed and, apparently, some of the functionallity of previous version has been lost.

So, I think that this is time to start thinking about whether nyroModal is the right plugin to choose.

I see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756342/whats-your-favorite-jquery-modal-plugin but I'm not asking for a jQuery plugin, but a JavaScript plugin. The one that you prefer.

This is the functionallity I need:

- Launch the modal using an anchor
- Launch the modal manually and specify its content
- Ability to customize all its content
- Ability to attach callbacks on specific modal events
- Updated documentation

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most of the best modal layers are built using a particular framework (i.e. jQuery, mootools, dojo, etc).

By the way, I used several times [highslide](http://highslide.com/) and it's very powerful!! No frameworks needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a mootools fan, and this plugin is my favorite at the moment.  It does modal for images, videos, and etc. http://iaian7.com/webcode/mediaboxAdvanced

if you are looking for something similar to what facebook as.  David Walsh has a modal plugin called LightBox and its great.  http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox

Both of these plugins are based off Mootools framework.